# Proving determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

$$\det \begin{pmatrix}
0&x_1&x_2&\ldots&x_n\\
x_1&a_{11}&a_{12}&\ldots&a_{1n}\\
x_2&a_{21}&a_{22}&\ldots&a_{2n}\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
x_n&a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\ldots&a_{nn}\\
\end{pmatrix} = -\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}x_ix_j.$$

where $A_{ij}\ \text{is the cofactor of }\ a_{ij}\ \text {and}\ n>1.$

My question is proving this problem.

First, I tried to take the cofactor expansion along the first row.

But I don't know what I do next.

Please give me some hints for proving this problem

Comment: The next thing to do is a cofactor expansion along the first column of each of the cofactors of your first expansion.

Comment: What exactly is a cofactor, may I ask?

Comment: @Andreas Caranti I'll try it!

Comment: @user477343 Cofactor is A_{ij}=(-1)^(i+j) det(M_{ij}) det(M_{ij}) is submatrix deleting the i row and j column of A

Comment: I need more context than that, hahah. I just learned about using matrices yesterday to solve for simultaneous equations (though I have been familiar with their determinants). I'd nevertheless hate to go off-topic.

Comment: @Andreas Caranti I computed the cofactor expansion along the first column of each  n by n submatrix... But how can I do?? I'm a little hazy about what to do next...